# Filter with select options values

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, onchange

I have a categories dropdown and multiple divs with class names, i want when the user selects and option from the dropdown to filter the divs according to the chosen option, like for example i have a category called makeup when the user selects it i want to only show the divs with the class makeup, here is what i have tried:

```js
$('#categories').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == "makeup") {
    $('.makeup').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(".makeup").not('.' + value).fadeOut();
    $('.makeup').filter('.' + value).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categories">
  <option selected disabled>Choose category</option>
  <option value="makeup">Make-up</option>
  <option value="cafes">Cafes</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="makeup">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="makeup">
  Div 2
</div>
<div class="makeup">
  Div 3
</div>
<div class="other">
  Div 4
</div>
```

Comment: Given that the selectors in your else statement are only using makeup, you're never going to show the element with the `other` class.  `not()` and `filter()` only return a subset of the previous search.  It will not include elements that were not previously found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Put a common class "category" on all the divs.
- Bind the change handler to the select
- When it changes, fadeOut all the options, and fadeIn the ones that match the value as a class

```js
$('#categories').on('change', function(e) {
  $('.category')
    .fadeOut()
    .filter('.'+ e.target.value)
    .fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categories">
  <option selected disabled>Choose category</option>
  <option value="makeup">Make-up</option>
  <option value="cafes">Cafes</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="category makeup">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="category makeup">
  Div 2
</div>
<div class="category makeup">
  Div 3
</div>
<div class="category other">
  Div 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works as requested, I've just added the class `.category-option` to the elements you are fading in and out.

---

## Demo

```js
$('#categories').change(function() {

  // Get value of selected option
  var val = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

  // Fadeout all that are not linked
  $(".category-option").fadeOut();

  // Fade in appropriate options
  $(".category-option." + val).fadeIn();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="categories">
  <option selected disabled>Choose category</option>
  <option value="makeup">Make-up</option>
  <option value="cafes">Cafes</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="category-option makeup">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="category-option makeup">
  Div 2
</div>
<div class="category-option makeup">
  Div 3
</div>
<div class="category-option other">
  Div 4
</div>
```